# A question to the derived length in modular group algebras

Tags: finite-groups, lie-algebras, p-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number, $G=:G_1$ a (non-Abelian) finite p-Group and $K$ a finite field with $\operatorname{char}(K)=p$. It is well-known that the group $G_2:=1+\operatorname{rad}(KG)$ is a p-group containing $G$.

My questions are:

1.) When does it happen that the derived length of $G_2$ is equal to the derived length of $G_1$?

2.) When does it happen that the Lie derived length of $KG_2$ is equal to the Lie derived length of $KG_1$?

Conjecture: If the length are equal, then the size of the derived subgroup of $G$ is bounded.

Comment: If a group has cyclic center of order $p^k$ and is of class 2, then derived length of group ring is $\rm{log}_2(p^k +1)$ rounded up. Maybe that could give easy examples for second question.

Comment: Thanks I know this theorem. A similar one is also valid for the group of units.

Comment: What do you mean by "on what terms"? Do you mean "When does it happen that"?

Comment: Yes, I have adjusted the questions accordingly.

Comment: we should close the topic.